# Magento2 How to debug search error?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 getting error when I search for digits 1 & 2

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 3, query was: SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '46') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '46') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (())
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 3
```

How to debug this?

Comment: You should disable custom module one by one until you find the one that is causing this issue. Try to start with custom modules that are more likely to be used in the search. The bug itself is related to your last AND that is empty : AND (())

Comment: Hi Arjun, did you solve this issue? I think we have the same problem